# Solidity: How to send a nested struct as parameter?

Tags: solidity, web3js

I am trying to send a nested struct to smart contract, but the transaction reverts:

```
const person = {
  name: "Me",
  age: 24,
  car: {
    id: 1,
    color: "black"
}

myContract.methods.addPerson(person).send({from: "0x3b0282D31174B927e102bA71d80dF34F4e596Fc4", gas:300000}, (error, result) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                } else {
                    console.log(result);
                });
```

this always throws:

```
(node:17276) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:
{
  "blockHash": "0x84647034828b4adf766a5bb55d19a32d665ba7e8c9cbcde4f2ecd8f3b112a13a",
  "blockNumber": 49378,
  "contractAddress": null,
  "cumulativeGasUsed": 300000,
  "from": "0x3b0282d31174b927e102ba71d80df34f4e596fc4",
  "gasUsed": 300000,
  "logsBloom": "0x000000000000000000000000000000000...",
  "status": false,
  "to": "0x37fe85f3a96a5fc1f9396ec42ae197d73a239ad7",
  "transactionHash": "0x43f0508b4419525b0eb4ab5a40765a3991ba152ba70c2731c6892d1253c9dfac",
  "transactionIndex": 0,
  "events": {}
}
```

If I send a simple struct it works fine

**NB: I am using web3 1.0.0-beta.37**

Comment: can you show the solidity function

Comment: i am not sure how you are trying to send the car object to handle it in solidity

Comment: You forgot a closing bracket.